# Error in running apex code in vs code studio

Tags: java, visual-studio, version, apex, salesforce-lightning

I'm facing issue while trying to run Apex code in vs code studio, i have installed the jdk 17 set the path check on cmd as well, everything seems fine still in vs code i'm getting this error "Running java command C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\bin\java -XshowSettings:prop:

Unable to activate the Apex Language Server - Running java command C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\bin\java -XshowSettings:properties -version failed with error: spawn C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\bin\java ENOENT

can someone please guide me?
Thank you.

I tried reinstallation but still no luck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\bin\java` the path is incorrect, note that there are two `bin` subdirectories in it.